# Contextual type 'Emoji' cannot be used with array literal

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, emoji

I'm trying to follow an exercise in the book *App Development with Swift* (Chapter 4 Tabel View).

The exercise tells me to add a property "emojis" of type `[Emoji]` to the `viewControllerClass`. The code is as follows:

```
 var emojis: [Emoji] = [
        [Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Grinning Face", description: "A typical smiley face.", usage: "happiness"),
         ]
    ]
```

But this line of code throws the error:

> Contextual type "Emoji" cannot be used with array literal.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
var emojis: [Emoji] = [Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Grinning Face", description: "A typical smiley face.", usage: "happiness")]
```

You are creating array of arrays. But you are var is declared as an array of Emoji type.

Answer (score 0):

This shows the solution a bit more clearly:

```
var emojis: [Emoji] = [Emoji(symbol: "", 
                             name: "Grinning Face", 
                             description: "A typical smiley face.",
                             usage: "happiness"), 
                       Emoji(symbol: "", 
                            name: "Confused Face", 
                            description: "A confused, puzzled face.", 
                            usage: "unsure what to think; displeasure")]
```